# GCP data centre fire safety details

Tags: google-cloud-platform, physical-security

I've been asked by a customer to provide fire safety details for Google Cloud Platform.  They require it for their procurement data security policies.  We use the europe_west2 London region to host their services and data.  Is there any way to find out the fire safety details of this, or other data centres?  I've tried extensively to find it through the GCP console and documentation and I've drawn a blank, and there is no contact available with the basic support plan that we're currently on.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check Google's [compliance list](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/compliance-reports-manager) for any relevant reports. I am not your compliance person however, you need someone qualified to address the specifics of your jurisdiction and situation.

[Basic support](https://cloud.google.com/support) is billing only. Pay for a support plan so you can ask GCP technical questions.

---

Regarding business continuity, any single data center could suffer a disaster. If not burning down, perhaps flooding or wind damage. If your organization's services need to keep going even when their physical hosting fails, consider multiple data center redundancy.  On Google, this could mean spreading infrastructure across nearby zones, and copying backups to a remote region.

Further reading: [Architecting disaster recovery for cloud infrastructure outages](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/disaster-recovery)